# Fill input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a JavaScript solutions. I recived data from aweber after user subscribe, in success page. so url like:

```
http://example.com/success/?email=example@email.com&name=Jhon&custom_phone=0005551114&custom_location=USA
```

They give some javascript solutions to show data in webpage or success page...

Referance: https://help.aweber.com/entries/21696333-How-Do-I-Display-Subscribers-Names-or-Email-Addresses-On-My-Thank-You-Page-

So When I put

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("custom_phone")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("custom_location")</script>
```

value will show in my page. But How can I put the value in a input field in success page??

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="Jhon">
<input type="text" name="useremail" value="example@email.com">
<input type="text" name="phoneno" value="0005551114">
<input type="text" name="country" value="USA">
<input tyoe="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Javascript code a bit, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var formData = function() {  var query_string = (location.search) ? ((location.search.indexOf('#') != -1) ? location.search.substring(1, location.search.indexOf('#')) : location.search.substring(1)) : '';  
var elements = [];  
if(query_string) {     
    var pairs = query_string.split("&");     
    for(i in pairs) {     
        if (typeof pairs[i] == 'string') {           
            var tmp = pairs[i].split("=");           
            var queryKey = unescape(tmp[0]);           
            queryKey = (queryKey.charAt(0) == 'c') ? queryKey.replace(/\s/g, "_") : queryKey;   
            elements[queryKey] = unescape(tmp[1]);      
             }    
       } 
 }  
return {     
    display: function(key) {         
        if(elements[key]) {           
             document.write('<input type="text" name="' + key + '" value ="' + elements[key] + '"');         
         } 
         else {         
               document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");          
          }     
  }   
} 
}
(); </script>
```

And your HTML will look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("custom_phone")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("custom_location")</script>
<input tyoe="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yahoo!!!! You are a genius man :).. You are really a live saver :) .. I love you :)

Comment: Alex, your solutions is work.. see here: http://tiny.cc/customfrom ... I use integrate it with wordpress contact from 7 .. now when I click send button, I got email with details.. but page redirect in 404 page.. any solutions?